# Install angular-cli on VSTS

Tags: angular-cli, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to get my build pipeline up and running for an angular-cli app. As far as I can understand I need to install angular-cli with the globaly to be able to test the app.

I've been trying to follow this guide https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/05/17/integrating-angular-4-unit-tests-with-visual-studio-team-services-vsts/

But when I run the "Install Angular-CLI" step, I get the following error in VSTS

> 2017-07-23T19:10:50.7544696Z ##[section]Starting: Install Angular CLI
>   2017-07-23T19:10:50.7674698Z ==============================================================================
>   2017-07-23T19:10:50.7674698Z Task         : npm
>   2017-07-23T19:10:50.7674698Z Description  : Install and publish npm packages, or run an npm command. Supports npmjs.com and authenticated registries like Package Management.
>   2017-07-23T19:10:50.7674698Z Version      : 1.0.3
>   2017-07-23T19:10:50.7674698Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
>   2017-07-23T19:10:50.7674698Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613746)
>   2017-07-23T19:10:50.7674698Z ==============================================================================
>   2017-07-23T19:10:51.5557774Z ##[error]TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of null
>   2017-07-23T19:10:51.5587778Z ##[section]Finishing: Install Angular CLI

I've entered everything as shown in the link. Is it a bug somewhere, or anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you know what version of node/npm is installed on the VSTS server? Any node version prior to 6.9 could be problematic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You specified the command in the input box of **Working folder with package.json**, which is incorrect.

With 1.* version of NPM install task, you can select **custom** in **Command** input box, then specify command in the input box of **Command and arguments**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, guess that is what I get for "lets just get this done before quiting" yesterday, fixed it all, much appreciated